# Как написать два метода, которые будут загружать/выгружать файл(ы) с NextCloud хоста

Tags: c#, nextcloud

Прочитал на официальном сайте документацию API. Ничего толком не понятно. Документация старая, а сайт уже 10 раз обновили и все переместили. Пытался запрос делать, ничего не получается. Нашел на GitHub API NextCloud. Не понял как с ним работать.
https://github.com/nikkilocke/NextcloudApi

Мне только нужна помощь, чтобы написать 2 метода.

1. LoadDataAsync ...
2. UploadDataAsync ..

Comment: `Ничего толком не понятно` - это не причина, это отмаза. Показывайте как вы пробовали, показывайте документацию и так далее. Там же простые POST/GET/PUT/DEL запросы, не уж то так трудно найти даже тут, на SO решения и применить их?

Comment: `Не понял как с ним работать.` там же автор написал, как. Покрутите страницу ниже.